# gRPC-js + Angular ngx-grpc - Stream stops receiving messages after 4 received

Tags: grpc-web, grpc-js

I have a grpc-js server setup with a rpc method called getUsers(). When making the call from the client, I only receive 4 of the messages back, despite there being 6 sent.

Here's the client method:

```
const client = new UsersClient(environment.rpcHost);
    const params = new CMSQuery();
    client.getUsers(params).on('data', (message: User) => {
      const obj = message.toObject();
      console.log(`${obj.name} received`);
      this.users.push(obj);
    }).on('end', () => {
      console.log('End of request');
    });
```

And here's the server method:

```
    async getUsers(call: grpc.ServerWritableStream<CMSQuery, User>): Promise<any> {
        const params = call.request.toObject();
        this.collection.find({}).forEach(user => {
            const message = protoFromObject(User, user);
            call.write(message);
            console.log(`${user.name} sent`);
        }).finally(() => {
            console.log('Closing request');
            call.end();
        });
    }
```

The server has the following console output:

```
User1 sent
User2 sent
User3 sent
User4 sent
User5 sent
User6 sent
Closing Request
```

And yet the client only has the following console output:

```
User1 received
User2 received
User3 received
User4 received
End of request
```

Are there any obvious things that would cause this? Some sort of timeout? Can anyone give me some pointers as to where I should be looking as I'm really stuck at the moment.

Thanks

Comment: This sounds like something you should report on the grpc-js repository itself in the form of a reproducible bug:

https://github.com/grpc/grpc-node/issues/new?assignees=&labels=&template=bug_report.md

Comment: @Nicholas Noble, Turns out there was an assertion error that was being suppressed, once I fixed the data type in one of the users being emitted, the error was resolved.